# How to work with date_select form helper without a model in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-helpers

I have a variable `@the_date` and a date_select form helper without an associated model.

How to use `date_select` to display the appropriate HTML?

The following does not work:

```
<%= date_select "the_date", @the_date %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what finally worked:

```
<% @the_date = Date.strptime(@the_date_string, "%Y-%m-%d") %>
<%= date_select("the_date_string", "", :default => @the_date) %>
```

I am storing the date as a string. So, it needs to be converted to a date object before displaying in the HTML form, and converted back to a string before saving in the database.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
<% @the_date = Time.now %>
<%= date_select("my_date", "my_date", :default => @the_date) %>
```

Comment: This helped me find what worked. Thank you!!!! `<%= date_select("the_date", "", :default => @the_date ) %>`

Comment: De nada, you needed the fake "object_name" and "attribute" options in the helper.